# List views' ArrayAdapter list updated twice when called notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

i try to invoke notifyDataSetChange() to redraw the data in the ArrayAdapter, but the whole data in the ArrayAdapter will be redrawn twice.

This is the activity_search.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <view
            class = "com.search.widget.ClearableEditText"
            android:id = "@+id/searchText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search Tours"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />


        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/result_list"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
                android:divider="@color/Orange"
                android:dividerHeight="1px"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loadingResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the layout for each row is the listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rows"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Tours"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Authors"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how i initialise the ListView and ArrayAdapter:

```
 resultiew = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.result_list);
        this.myadp = new myAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                results);
        resultiew.setAdapter(myadp);

        // render result
        resultChangeListener();
```

resultChangeListerner() is a thread that used to call notifyDataSetChange() when the data that should be draw is updated, here is the code:

```
private void resultChangeListener() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (SearchActivity.listModified == true) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                SearchActivity.listModified = false;

                                resetInfos();
                                Log.e("change search location result",
                                        "there");
                                System.out.println("adapter size:"
                                        + myadp.list.size());
                                myadp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                System.out.println("listview count: "
                                        + resultiew.getCount());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

SearchActivity.listModified indicates where the data is updated.

Here is the code for resetInfos(), it clears the result set and add content to it.

```
private void resetInfos() {
    results.clear();
    toursTextViews.clear();
    authorsTextViews.clear();
    results.addAll(labels);
}
```

Below is my ArrayAdapter:

```
private class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public myAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.list = objects;
        }

        View row;

        private List<String> list;

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            {
                String rowMetaContent[] = this.list.get(position).split(
                        SearchActivity.delimiter);

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_results_row_layout,
                        parent, false);

                if (position == 0) {
                    TextView headerTours = (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.Tours);
                    TextView headerAuthors = (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.Authors);
                    setHeaderStyle(headerTours, "Tours");
                    setHeaderStyle(headerAuthors, "Authors");

                }

                else {
                    try {

                        TextView headerTours = (TextView) row
                                .findViewById(R.id.Tours);
                        TextView headerAuthors = (TextView) row
                                .findViewById(R.id.Authors);

                        switch (rowMetaContent.length) {
                        case 7:
                            headerTours.setPadding(4, 16, 1, 16);
                            headerTours.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                            this.setTextStyle(headerTours, rowMetaContent[0]);
                            keyWordSearchTours.add(rowMetaContent[2]);
                            toursTextViews.add(headerTours);
                            headerTours.setOnClickListener(onclicklistener);

                            headerAuthors.setPadding(4, 16, 1, 16);
                            headerAuthors.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            authorsTextViews.add(headerAuthors);
                            headerAuthors.setOnClickListener(onclicklistener);

                            this.setTextStyle(headerAuthors, rowMetaContent[4]);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            headerTours.setPadding(4, 16, 1, 16);
                            headerTours.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            this.setTextStyle(headerTours, rowMetaContent[0]);
                            keyWordSearchTours.add(rowMetaContent[2]);
                            toursTextViews.add(headerTours);
                            headerTours.setOnClickListener(onclicklistener);

                            headerAuthors.setPadding(4, 16, 1, 16);
                            headerAuthors.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            break;

                        default:
                            headerTours.setPadding(4, 16, 1, 16);
                            headerTours.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            // this.setTextStyle(headerTours, "");
                            keyWordSearchTours.add("");

                            headerAuthors.setPadding(4, 16, 1, 16);
                            headerAuthors.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            this.setTextStyle(headerAuthors, rowMetaContent[0]);
                            authorsTextViews.add(headerAuthors);
                            headerAuthors.setOnClickListener(onclicklistener);
                            break;

                        }

                         System.out.println(this.list.get(position));
                         System.out.println(list.size());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                return row;
            }
        }

        public void setHeaderStyle(TextView textView, String header) {
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.customshape_header);
            textView.setPadding(4, 2, 1, 1);
            row.setEnabled(false);
            textView.setEnabled(false);

            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textView.setText(header);

        }

        public void setTextStyle(TextView textView, String result) {
            try {

                // replace all * in result
                String partString[] = result.split("\\$");
                String newResult = partString[0];
                int start = Integer.parseInt(partString[1]);
                int end = Integer.parseInt(partString[2]);
                final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                        newResult);

                final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(
                        Color.rgb(255, 97, 0));
                final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(
                        android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

                sb.setSpan(fcs, start, end + 1,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                sb.setSpan(bss, start, end + 1,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                // make them also bold
                textView.setText(sb);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error:  " + result);
                Log.d("exception error", e.toString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is the output from LogCat, the list size in ArrayAdapter is 3, but the getView() is called 6 times.

```
09-20 15:47:35.530: I/System.out(4095): adapter size:3
09-21 15:47:35.530: I/System.out(4095): Position: 1
09-21 15:47:35.530: I/System.out(4095): josh's tour1$0$3###@@@Content###@@@josh-1410695945754###@@@Tours###@@@josh$0$3###@@@Content###@@@Authors
09-21 15:47:35.530: I/System.out(4095): Position: 2
09-21 15:47:35.530: I/System.out(4095): joshua's tour$0$3###@@@Content###@@@joshua's_tour-1409049012110###@@@Tours###@@@joshua$0$3###@@@Content###@@@Authors
09-21 15:47:35.540: I/System.out(4095): Position: 3
09-21 15:47:35.540: I/System.out(4095): joshua's tour$0$3###@@@Content###@@@joshua's_tour-1408968854379###@@@Tours###@@@joshua$0$3###@@@Content###@@@Authors
09-21 15:47:35.550: I/System.out(4095): Position: 1
09-21 15:47:35.550: I/System.out(4095): josh's tour1$0$3###@@@Content###@@@josh-1410695945754###@@@Tours###@@@josh$0$3###@@@Content###@@@Authors
09-21 15:47:35.560: I/System.out(4095): Position: 2
09-21 15:47:35.560: I/System.out(4095): joshua's tour$0$3###@@@Content###@@@joshua's_tour-1409049012110###@@@Tours###@@@joshua$0$3###@@@Content###@@@Authors
09-21 15:47:35.570: I/System.out(4095): Position: 3
09-21 15:47:35.570: I/System.out(4095): joshua's tour$0$3###@@@Content###@@@joshua's_tour-1408968854379###@@@Tours###@@@joshua$0$3###@@@Content###@@@Authors
```

I tried to comment all my code just these lines in the onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle("");
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        ListView resultiew = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.result_list);
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.myadp = new myAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
        resultiew.setAdapter(myadp);
        results.add("hello"); 
}
```

And i got this logCat output:

```
09-21 16:26:42.490: I/System.out(8084): Position: 0
09-21 16:26:42.490: I/System.out(8084): hello
09-21 16:26:42.490: I/System.out(8084): 1
09-21 16:26:42.530: I/System.out(8084): Position: 0
09-21 16:26:42.530: I/System.out(8084): hello
09-21 16:26:42.530: I/System.out(8084): 1
09-21 16:26:42.560: I/System.out(8084): Position: 0
09-21 16:26:42.560: I/System.out(8084): hello
09-21 16:26:42.560: I/System.out(8084): 1
```

Comment: I tried comment myadp.notifyDataSetChanged() in resultChangeListener() then nothing displayed on the screen, so i think the problem is about the notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: When is the resultChangeListener Called? And when is `SearchActivity.listModified`? Only 3 items in the list? Please put  100 in them so you have a normal list to begin with. Indeed getView() for the first items is often called to often. I have seen this before. But that happens only for some of the first items..

Comment: Please do not only print list.size() to the log but also the position. There should not be a log entry for position 0.

Comment: `SearchActivity.listModified = false;`. That has to be done before you call runOnUiThread().

Comment: HI, thanks for your response. I am actually doing a search function, the results list will be filled with the search result. The results list is empty when the first time adapter was created, then the results list will be updated corresponds to the search result. To do the update i do the following things: 1. I created a adapter with a empty list called "results". 2. I start a thread by resultChangeListener() to check if the search result is updated for every 500ms.

Comment: 3. If the search result is updated, SearchActivity.listModified will be set to "True" and the new search result will be stored in a variable named "labels". 4. Instead of add items in "labels" to results list directly, i simply clear the results list and all "labels" to results list. 5. invoke myadp.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: If you hsve complaints of data beeing redrawn twice then do away with all your searches and threads and make a five code lines example that demonstrates this.

Comment: Hi greenapps, i comment all the codes just leave 5 lines. And get a strange logCat output. I also updated the layout xml file. Can you help me find out what's the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: Put 30 items in the listview first.

Answer (score -1):

When you set your adapter your data will be drawn. And again with notyfyDataSetChanged().

Comment: But the set in the adapter is empty at first. The problem is that the set in adapter will be drawn twice when notifyDataSetChanged() is invoked in resultChangeListener().

Comment: How do you 'see' that it is drawn twice?

Comment: Empty at first? You said: `try to invoke notifyDataSetChange() to redraw the data in the ArrayAdapter,`. What has there be to redrawn when it is empty?

Comment: Actually i am doing a search function, the results stores the search result, so it will keeps changing. But it is empty the first time ArrayAdapter was initialised.